# JQuery - Advanced Check box Handling

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have four fieldsets of checkboxes.  Each fieldset is a timeslot (12-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4) and within each fieldset, I have seminars (seminar 1, seminar 2, seminar3... etc.)

One can select to attend only one seminar per fieldset, or timeslot.
One cannot select the same seminar across multiple timeslots.
Some timeslots have unique seminars that do not appear in any other timeslot
All timeslots have an option to not attend a seminar during that timeslot.

So....
I'm using the following code to disable duplicate checkboxes across four fieldsets:

```
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $('input[type=checkbox][name='+name+']:not(#'+id+')')
        .attr('disabled',checked)
        .each(function(){
            lid = $(this).attr('id');
            if (checked) {
                $('label[for='+lid+']').addClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('label[for='+lid+']').removeClass('disabled');
            }

        });

});
  });
```

This is working perfectly, however, I also need to prevent the user from checking only one checkbox per fieldset... or alert them when they try to check off more than one checkbox within the fieldset.  Is there a way to edit the above script to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a multi-selector where only one element can be selected, why aren't you using radio buttons in your fieldsets as opposed to checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the number of checked checkboxes and do your validation from there

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    // get the checked elements in this fieldset    
    var numChkd = $(this).siblings(':checked').size();

    // do whatever kind of validation you need
    if(!numChkd && !this.checked){
        alert('Please select at least one');
        // keep it checked?
        $(this).attr('checked',true);
    };

});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CWJND/2/)

---

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CWJND/4/) -- Shows when you try to deselect more than 2. It's really only a matter of changing your validation to suit your needs though;

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    var numChkd = $(this).siblings(':checked').size();

    if(numChkd <= 1 && !this.checked){
        alert('Please select at least two');
        $(this).attr('checked',true);
    };

});
```

---

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CWJND/5/) to answer comment. It's just a matter of changing the if() statement.

```
if(numChkd >= 1){
    alert('Please select only one per fieldset');
    $(this).attr('checked',false);
};
```

---

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8kaY/2/) - I believe there is some issues w/ the html. Namely the onclick attached to each input. The reason why it wasn't working on your html is because it relies on traversing (e.g. finding the parent fieldset).

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    // get the fieldset class
    var fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset').attr('class');

    // set the number of checked
    var numChecked = $('.'+fieldset+' input:checked').size();

    // if more than 1
    if(numChecked > 1){
        alert('Please select only 1')
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks... I think I miscommunicated what I was asking for.  I am looking to prevent a user from selecting more than one checkbox within each fieldset.  All checkboxes are de-selected by default.

Comment: No problem, check out the last demo.

Comment: It's not working... I think it could be a conflict with the checkbox names being duplicated across fieldsets.  I have put my page code up here:http://jsfiddle.net/jweisberg/a8kaY/

Comment: It worked!  Thanks Jyoseph!  Can we also prevent the second checkbox from retaining it's checked value after the alert is displayed?

Comment: Something like: checkbox.checked = false; ?

Comment: Yep, you bet. Just do `$(this).attr('checked',false);`. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct so I get a reward for all of my hard work! ;-)

Comment: One more question... How do I add a validation script on submit of the form to ensure that the user has checked at least one checkbox for each fieldset?

Comment: Yes... That's what I was trying to accomplish, however it needs to be incorporated into the rest of the form validation... along with all other fields: http://jsfiddle.net/jweisberg/b4bYy/1/

Comment: Add a class to the main div that surrounds all 4 of your sessions. Something like .sessionBoxes. Then in the code I provided, change `$('fieldset',this).each(` to `$('fieldset.sessionBoxes',this).each(function(){` You could also remove the 'this' part and just do `$('fieldset.sessionBoxes').each(function(){`

Comment: It's not working... It runs through the other validation and submits the form without validating the checkbox fieldsets.